# How to focus a canvas element inside an object tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, onload

I have a canvas element like that:

```
<canvas id="board_canvas" width="114" tabindex="1" height="254" style="position: fixed; left:</canvas>
```

Inside in a object tag:

```
<object type="text/html" data="url" width="350" height="800">< /object>
```

I want this element focused when the page is loaded.

Comment: have you tried $(function(){ $('#board_canvas').focus();});   ?

Comment: i've tried it before ask the question, but isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't focus any HTML element inside an `Object` tag.

Everything inside an object tag is treated differently than other content as it defines embedded objects (aka plugins such as FlashPlayer etc.) from external resources (which of course canvas or other DOM elements are not).

> The HTML  Element (or HTML Embedded Object Element) represents
>   an external resource, which can be treated as an image, a nested
>   browsing context, or a resource to be handled by a plugin.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object)

If you want to use FlashPlayer if canvas is not available you need to do it the opposite way:

```
<canvas id="board_canvas" width... >
    <object>...</object>
</canvas>
```

This way you can use the `tabIndex` attribute and `focus()`:

```
$('#board_canvas').attr('tabIndex', 0).focus();
```